# Vincular dados no MongoDB

Tags: node.js, react, mongodb, mongoose

Model

```
    const AvaliacaoShema = new Schema({

    responsavel: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    time: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Time',
        required: true
    },

    pergunta: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Pergunta',
        required: true,
    }],

    Resposta: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Resposta',
        required: true
    }],    

}, {
    timestamps: true
})
module.exports = model('Avaliacao', AvaliacaoShema)


const Avaliacao = require('../models/Avaliacao')
```

Controller

```
module.exports = {
    async index(req, res) {
        await Avaliacao.find(req.body)
            .populate('pergunta')
            .populate('getResposta')
            .exec()
            .then((a) => res.json(a))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    },

    async show(req, res) {
        await Avaliacao.findById(req.params.id)
            .populate('pergunta')
            .populate('getResposta')
            .exec()
            .then((a) => res.json(a))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    },

    async create(req, res) {
        try {
            const avali = await Avaliacao.create(req.body)
            return res.json(avali)
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send({ error })
        }
    },

    async edit(req, res) {
        const avali = await Avaliacao.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, { new: true, runValidators: true })

        return res.json(avali)
    },
    async delete(req, res) {
        await Avaliacao.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)

        return res.send()
    }}
```

Bom dia pessoal, estou fazendo um sistema de questionário, que o admin adiciona a disciplina que respectivamente tem questões dela, tenho uma collection de de perguntas que consta disciplina + perguntas, fiz uma collection de resposta, que tem opções como Sim, Não e Não se Aplica, nesse collection em tela é a avaliação que tem que salvar pergunta e resposta, está salvando _id da pergunta e _id da resposta, mas não está vinculando elas, como faço para vincular a pergunta com a resposta, pois no final preciso fazer um calculo,

Agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que entendi melhor seu problema, está na modelagem do seu schema.

**O `Schema.Types.ObjectId` é usado para referenciar outro schema, não se auto referencia em um mesmo schema. Para isso você teria que usar cada schema especificamente para cada um.**

Um para usuário, outro para pergunta e outro para resposta.

Na sua pergunta você coloca que:

1. > tenho uma collection de de perguntas que consta disciplina + perguntas
2. > fiz uma collection de resposta, que tem opções como Sim, Não e Não se Aplica
3. > nesse collection em tela é a avaliação que tem que salvar pergunta e resposta, está salvando _id da pergunta e _id da resposta, mas não está vinculando ela

Você fez um schema (um model) chamado `Avaliacoes` contendo os itens `pergunta` e `resposta`, para fazer o que você quer, necessita de separar cada um deles em arquivos separados.

**Avaliação** - Cria o schema de avaliação e recolhe dos outros. Se quiser pode referenciar o responsável à um professor.

```
/**Local onde está seu conector do banco.*/
const mongoose = require('../../database/mongodb')

const Avaliacao = new mongoose.Schema({

    responsavel: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    pergunta: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Pergunta',
        required: true,
    }],

    Resposta: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Resposta',
        required: true
    }],   

}, {
    timestamps: true
})

const Avaliacao = mongoose.model.('Avaliacao', AvaliacaoSchema)
module.exports = Avaliacao
```

**Pergunta** - schema de pergunta

```
/**Local onde está seu conector do banco.*/
const mongoose = require('../../database/mongodb')

const PerguntaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    /**Campos do que você quiser para a pergunta*/

})

const Pergunta = mongoose.model.('Pergunta', PerguntaSchema)
module.exports = Pergunta
```

**Resposta** - schema de resposta. Pode referenciar aqui dentro um aluno.

```
/**Local onde está seu conector do banco.*/
const mongoose = require('../../database/mongodb')

const respostaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    /**Campos do que você quiser para a pergunta*/

})

const Resposta = mongoose.model.('Resposta', respostaSchema)
module.exports = Resposta
```

**Controller**
No seu controller, você precisaria percorrer cada pergunta e resposta para atribuir depois às avaliações, fazendo o código para avaliação receber as perguntas em um método `post`com um `async`:

```
await Promise.all(perguntas.map(Pergunta => {
    const avaliacaoPergunta = new Pergunta({ ...pergunta, avaliacao: avaliacao._id })

await avaliacaoPergunta.save()

avaliacao.perguntas.push(avaliacaoPergunta)
}))

await avaliacao.save()

return res.send({ avaliacao })
```

Para popular, você pode fazer em um método `get` com um `async`, podendo ser feito na listagem e no registro único:

```
const avaliacoes = await Avaliacao.find().populate(['perguntas'])

return res.send({ avaliacoes })
```

Faça o mesmo para as respostas e seja feliz.

Creio que seja isto, não?